# Convert htaccess file to web.config to run Php on IIS 7

Tags: .htaccess, iis, iis-7, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I need to convert .htaccess  to web.config in order to run php on iis 7. Any Ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: I never understood why people insist on using IIS with all its problem in running things like PHP. But I was told that there is a conversion tool delivered by MS that automatically converts .htaccess style files to what IIS requires instead. Have you tried that tool?

Answer (score 1):

The URL Rewriting module's import rules from .htaccess wizard generated the following rules:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="non-existent paths to index.php">
          <match url="^test/(.+)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="test/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The request `/test/` will cause IIS to fire `/test/index.php` so `(.*)` is unnecessary and `(.+)` is more appropriate.

Comment: this might be helpful: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules