# How to route a url in PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, url, routes, url-routing

I would like to use my current index.php?par=1 in a directory-style. Thus, /par/1  or just /1 and use that value (1) in the index.php script. The problem with the routing solutions I found is that they ask you to edit the .htaccess file - which I don't have because I use IIS on Windows.

How can route a url in PHP on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Some versions of IIS can use something similar. Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: The [URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module might be what you are looking for

Comment: If you still want to use .htaccess better use apache server on windows.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869747/convert-htaccess-file-to-web-config-to-run-php-on-iis-7

Comment: @Machavity: I use IIS 7.

Comment: @Vincent: Nope, I don't want to use apache. I use IIS 7 on Windows.